# Are werewolves in Harry Potter powerful even while in human form?

Tags: harry-potter, werewolf

When we are introduced to werewolves with Lupin he doesn't seem to have any special characteristic while in human form. We can presume, since is [canon](https://www.pottermore.com/writing-by-jk-rowling/werewolves) information, that any wound he inflicts will leave lasting scars, but not much more.

Yet we meet Fenrir Greyback who, while in human form, shows some arguably superhuman feats:

- Animal appearance
- Described as "a grey blur" when running
- Some resistance to the Stunning Spell (in Malfoy Mannor)

Even more, he plans to build a [Werewolf Army](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Werewolf_army) to take on the wizarding world, which admittedly can be composed mostly of discriminated wizards with no special abilities but it seems unlikely to harbor that thought with such an inferior force (unless werewolves are really powerful).

So my question is: are werewolves in a human form stronger/faster/sturdier than other wizards? If not, are the features we see in Greyback superhuman? Is Greyback the only werewolf with a super-powered human form?

Comment: Pure speculation, hence a comment not an answer, but maybe Greyback has discovered a spell or potion that allows him to keep some of his werewolfness when there's not a full moon?

Comment: @WiggotheWookie not unlikely considering his close association with a Wizard known to change his own appearance by messing around Dark Magic

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Greyback seems to be an unusual case, so his abilities may be atypical.

Dumbledore certainly seems surprised at how much of his werewolf traits Greyback retained even when it wasn't a full moon. This shows that the amount of abilities and werewolf traits Greyback are unusually strong in some way, whether that's them being simply stronger than usual, or the abilities remaining present at all.

> “Am I to take it that you are attacking even without the full moon now? This is most unusual … you have developed a taste for human flesh that cannot be satisfied once a month?’
>
> ‘That’s right,’ said Greyback. ‘Shocks you, that, does it, Dumbledore? Frightens you?’
>
> ‘Well, I cannot pretend it does not disgust me a little,’ said Dumbledore. 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 27 (The Lightning-Struck Tower)*</sup></sub>

From this, we can gather that Greyback is more vicious than the typical werewolf.

**There are werewolves who lead similar lives, but it's not clear if they have super abilities.**

Remus Lupin goes to live undercover with other werewolves who choose not to attempt to live among wizards to convince them not to join the Dark Lord. These werewolves live hidden from society, and they steal and sometimes kill for food.

> “However, it has been difficult gaining their trust. I bear the unmistakeable signs of having tried to live among wizards, you see, whereas they have shunned normal society and live on the margins, stealing – and sometimes killing – to eat.” 
> <sub><sup>*- Harry Potter and the Half-Blood Prince, Chapter 27 (The Lightning-Struck Tower)*</sup></sub>

Their base personalities are more prone to violence than Lupin, but it's unclear whether this means they have lesser versions of Greyback's special abilities or if they simply have none, and the abilities only occur when a werewolf is as violent as Greyback.

Comment: A notable point in your quote is the use of "developed" and fuzzface's agreement.

Comment: I had forgotten about that piece of exchange with Dumbledore, it points to Greyback being an special case.

Comment: I would argue it's because he really, really, really resents wizards. Look at what he did to Remus simply because it was suggested that his kind should be killed - by Remus's father in fact. He's a fanatic. As for an army I seem to recall that his goal was to turn as many wizards/witches into werewolves as possible - **which ironically would make the others hate them even more...**

Comment: If I may, I think your answer could use the quote about "Lupin being very pale - was the full moon approaching?" from one of the memories Harry went in (I don't remember which one, sorry! :p ). It would rather show that werewolves aren't much healthier (don't know about you, but if I'm pale, it's generally that I don't feel so we'll, not that I'm at my peak); though you could argue that it's only before the full moon. In any case, that kind of underlines the point about Greyback being an odd one.

Comment: @Pryftan That seems very likely. It’s clear that Greyback really hates wizards, likely because of werewolves’ low status in the wizarding world. He’s obviously furious when Lyall says werewolves deserve death. That’s somewhat understandable, no one likes people saying everyone like them should die. As you’ve said, he’s certainly not winning over any wizards by what he’s doing, though.

Comment: @Miss Bella There's another way to look at the question too isn't there? A werewolf is still a wizard/witch and they can be a formidable opponent there too. Remus arguably was too it's just he was bested by - well, you know :) This is going by the title of the question itself though. But yes Greyback utterly despises wizards and for the reasons you cite too. And indeed he's only going to anger wizards more. The things people oft do when they feel alienated; yet it's more likely when you're repeatedly told that you do X that you will do exactly that even if it further alienates you. Truly sad.

Comment: @Pryftan That’s true as well - most werewolves are also wizards, so can have power in their magical ability as well as in werewolf-related ability. Remus seemed to be fairly talented magically, but was actually depleted by his ‘monthly affliction’ whereas Greyback seemed to favor brute force over magic. Interestingly, in many ways, Remus and Greyback were polar opposites - one embraced wizardkind and feared his werewolf side, Greyback embraced his werewolf ability and hated wizards. That’s true - often hearing the same misconceptions makes people more likely to do exactly that.

Comment: @Miss Bella: I couldn't agree more. I think you hit enter too soon again? And I thought it is mentioned in the book that Dolohov killed him? I was thinking for some reason you - Miss Bella, that is - were the one who killed Remus but perhaps it was you who got Tonks? Either way Remus was powerful and yes they were certainly polar opposites. Because Greyback didn't have the love, compassion, etc., that Remus was given, it is more expected that Greyback would be more - well the way he is. Not a guarantee but in that's how it turned out in his case. Character weakness, really.

Comment: @Pryftan Thanks! Yes I did - I think I was able to fix it this time though. In the books, Harry just saw both Remus and Tonks dead. Yes, I got Tonks - as I told the Dark Lord, she’s no niece of mine and I’m glad to prune the family tree! ;) Agreed, Remus was loved and cared for and there’s no evidence that Greyback was. In addition, Greyback may not have gotten much of an education - Dumbledore had to make special arrangements for Remus since werewolves weren’t allowed at Hogwarts. That might also be why he tends to favor brute force - he might not have actually been a fully trained wizard.

Comment: I would argue that Greyback is more than atypical but uncanny, too, as an aside. The first quote you cite is the example I was thinking of actually. That's an interesting thought about Greyback; on the other hand doesn't he Apparate the trio along with the other snatchers to Malfoy Manor? That's an interesting thing to ponder... And as for the other dialogue on chat (yes this is OT but I don't care) - it's silly that and you might as well just delete the apologising for it (it's not your fault anyway). I can then (if I remember) delete this comment and add it without this.